# TypeError: expected bytes, Descriptor found

Tags: python, tensorflow, tfrecord

How do I fix the following error traceback regarding `tf.record`?

```py
(tensorflow1) c:\tensorflow1\models\research\object_detection>python generate_tfrecord.py --csv_input=data/train_labels.csv --output_path=data/train.record --image_dir=(image directory)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "generate_tfrecord.py", line 17, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "C:\Users\Dell-Oguz\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "C:\Users\Dell-Oguz\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 52, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework.graph_pb2 import *
  File "C:\Users\Dell-Oguz\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\core\framework\graph_pb2.py", line 15, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework import node_def_pb2 as tensorflow_dot_core_dot_framework_dot_node__def__pb2
  File "C:\Users\Dell-Oguz\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\core\framework\node_def_pb2.py", line 15, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework import attr_value_pb2 as tensorflow_dot_core_dot_framework_dot_attr__value__pb2
  File "C:\Users\Dell-Oguz\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\core\framework\attr_value_pb2.py", line 15, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework import tensor_pb2 as tensorflow_dot_core_dot_framework_dot_tensor__pb2
  File "C:\Users\Dell-Oguz\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\core\framework\tensor_pb2.py", line 15, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework import resource_handle_pb2 as tensorflow_dot_core_dot_framework_dot_resource__handle__pb2
  File "C:\Users\Dell-Oguz\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\core\framework\resource_handle_pb2.py", line 91, in <module>
    __module__ = 'tensorflow.core.framework.resource_handle_pb2'
TypeError: expected bytes, Descriptor found
```

Comment: i am facing the same error. I figured it out by reading this site:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/35208 Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

Try this, worked for me

```
pip install protobuf-py3
pip install --upgrade protobuf
```

Comment: Worked for me but gave me another error. Referring to this answer to solve the problem I'm currently facing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60423758/keras-is-not-importing-typeerror-can-only-concatenate-str-not-list-to-str

Answer (score 0):

I get the same error when I installed tensorflow with `conda install -c anaconda tensorflow-gpu` over existing tenforflow.

Remove existing environment and create a new one. Then run `conda install -c anaconda tensorflow-gpu` .

Comment: Hi
I did "conda uninstall -c anaconda tensorflow-gpu", then I run "conda install -c anaconda tensorflow-gpu" but I get same error.
Could you give detail?

Comment: Remove environment with `conda remove --name myenv --all` then create new environment `conda create -n mynewenv python=3.6` .

Then run `activate mynewenv` and `conda install -c anaconda tensorflow-gpu`

Comment: I am not sure why it is not fixed. You can try install cuda, cudnn and keras step by step. Check below links.
first install cuda; 
https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads  (I recommend 10.0 or 10.1)
https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/sdk/cudnn-install/index.html#install-windows
after that try pip install tensorflow-gpu

Answer (score 0):

Probably it's due to unmatched tensorflow and tensorboard versions.

I solved it after creating a separate conda environment for my code.

Answer (score 0):

In my case,

`pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow-gpu==1.15.0`

did the job :).