# Tensorflow TypeError: expected bytes, Descriptor found

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, anaconda

I've been following this tutorial for recognising an object using machine learning:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rgpfk6eYxJA

I've followed all the instructions on what to install and how, including those in this related tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RplXYjxgZbw

I tried both with their version and the newest available versions of the software. With the exception that I create the virtual environment like this:

`conda create -n tensorflow1 pip python=3.6`

Because the tensorflow module isn't yet compatible with python 3.7.

After I install all the packages needed, also described here:

https://github.com/EdjeElectronics/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-API-Tutorial-Train-Multiple-Objects-Windows-10

Under **2d. Set up new Anaconda virtual environment**

and go through the code in the video, I run into a error when I run

`python generate_tfrecord.py --csv_input=images\train_labels.csv --image_dir=images\train --output_path=train.record`

which is working in the video at 19:35.

The error is

```
2019-12-11 10:13:43.410540: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_100.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_100.dll not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "generate_tfrecord.py", line 17, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 98, in <module>
    from tensorflow_core import *
  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 947, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow1\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\__init__.py", line 52, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework.graph_pb2 import *
  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\core\framework\graph_pb2.py", line 16, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework import node_def_pb2 as tensorflow_dot_core_dot_framework_dot_node__def__pb2
  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\core\framework\node_def_pb2.py", line 16, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework import attr_value_pb2 as tensorflow_dot_core_dot_framework_dot_attr__value__pb2
  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\core\framework\attr_value_pb2.py", line 16, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework import tensor_pb2 as tensorflow_dot_core_dot_framework_dot_tensor__pb2
  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\core\framework\tensor_pb2.py", line 16, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework import resource_handle_pb2 as tensorflow_dot_core_dot_framework_dot_resource__handle__pb2
  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\core\framework\resource_handle_pb2.py", line 16, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework import tensor_shape_pb2 as tensorflow_dot_core_dot_framework_dot_tensor__shape__pb2
  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\core\framework\tensor_shape_pb2.py", line 112, in <module>
    '__module__' : 'tensorflow.core.framework.tensor_shape_pb2'
TypeError: expected bytes, Descriptor found
```

This problem is the same that appears in the jupyter kernel when I run the imports that appear in the video at 14:25

How do I fix the

> TypeError: expected bytes, Descriptor found

Error?

And what's with

> Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_100.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_100.dll not found

That also appears?

I can also share this with you, in the second tutorial, the one just about installing tensorflow-gpu library, after I create an account for cuDNN and download it as inscribed, I only get a **cudnn64_7.dll** file in C:\cuda\bin which is in my system path environment variable, just as are

- C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1\bin
- C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1\libnvvp and
- C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1\extras\CUPTI\lib64,

as instructed in the tutorial. As you can see, I have version 10.1 of Cuda and cuDNN and the paths are a bit different. The GPU Driver is also updated.

P.S. in the tensorflow installing tutorial, the test code doesn't work either.

This is all the information I think I have to offer.

I've been trying to solve this problem for 4-5 days at this point (and this is not my first video I watch to get a .record file for an image recognition neural network)

and the solutions for this particular problem offered in [TypeError: expected bytes, Descriptor found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59145666/typeerror-expected-bytes-descriptor-found) or any other place on stackoverflow are not useful.

What should I do?

P.S. The tensorflow-gpu version I have is 2.0.0, and it might not be compatible with Cuda and cuDNN. It might be why I only have a cudnn64_7.dll file and not a cudart64_100.dll file. If no one has other solutions, I'll just install tensorflow 1.5 and try the software again.

If someone has another solution however, by all means, post it. I'll post a reply if it works. I'll edit this if it doesn't.

Comment: any update on this? I'm stuck here as well. I'm wondering if we are using different versions of tensorflow then the tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

I've followed a different tutorial, however came across the same errors. 
In case anyone is still wondering, I've fixed it by updating the tensorflow version from 1.5 originally to 1.15

```
pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow-gpu==1.15.0
```

This is the official issue where I got the idea [from](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/35208).

As for the second part,

```
Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_100.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_100.dll not found
```

This is an issue with the CUDA drivers. In short, there's compatibility issue between the tensorflow and your GPU. In most cases, don't worry too much, since it will default to using your CPU over GPU for training of a model. In case you really want to use the GPU (for better performance etc) check if it's supported. You can check similarly asked [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50622525/which-tensorflow-and-cuda-version-combinations-are-compatible), or from an [official source](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus).

Alternatively, since you've installed CUDA 10.1, as per official [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu), you'll need to upgrade tensorflow 2.1.0 or above to make it work.

Personally, I had to opt to using tensorflow 1.15 over 2.2.0 and installing CUDA 9.0 to make everything run. However, I'm working on a laptop with a mobile 1050 GPU, and no matter what, I couldn't get it to run otherwise.